# How do i do unit test with golang for mongodb ? can you share some sample code as well?

Tags: mongodb, go

We are using martini as web framework and gopkg.in/check.v1 for testing. I am not sure whether i have to create a testing database and test it

Comment: The question could be improved but is interesting nonetheless, I hope it won't be closed. In particular, I'm wondering how can one get 100% test coverage with a test DB since it won't fail in all places it could fail?

Comment: That's a general question not related to Go/Mongo. On one hand, if you don't create a database, your tests aren't really unit tests but integration tests. On the other hand, if you create a database and inject synthetic data to it, you might miss bugs due to schema change. So it depends on the use case. I'm not using mongo but I have different cases I'm using either method.